# Getting ObjectContext Disposed exception when accessing data from a Session Variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've tried asking this question several times now and either no one knows the answer or they think it's been answered before. I have not found an answer yet so I don't think it has.

Using MVC5 EF6.

I have a search that I run against a repository. Before leaving the Controller I place the results of the Search (using ToList() to make sure the results are enumerated). Then I return the View passing the results. This works fine.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public async Task<ActionResult> SearchDispensaries(DispensarySearchModel model,
    int pageNumber = 1, int pageSize = 10, string sortByField = "Dba", bool sortAscending = true) {
    IEnumerable<Dispensary> found = null;
    if ((model == null || !model.NewSearch) && Session["DispensariesFound"] != null) {
        found = Session["DispensariesFound"] as List<Dispensary>;
    }
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        found = await _dispensaries.SearchAsync(model, sortByField, sortAscending);
        Session["DispensariesFound"] = found;
    }
    ViewBag.PageNumber = pageNumber;
    ViewBag.PageSize = pageSize;
    ViewBag.SortByField = sortByField;
    ViewBag.SortAscending = sortAscending;
    ViewBag.SortingEnabled = true;
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
        return PartialView("_Dispensaries", found);
    }

    return View("DispensarySearchResults", found);
}
```

In the View I have the ability to change pages or sorting rules. I have another function which does this...

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public ActionResult SortAndPageDispensaries(int pageNumber = 1, int pageSize = 10, string sortByField = "Dba",
        bool sortAscending = true) {
        var found = (Session["DispensariesFound"] as IEnumerable<Dispensary>) ?? new List<Dispensary>();
        found = _dispensaries.ApplySort(found, sortByField, sortAscending).ToList();
        ViewBag.PageNumber = pageNumber;
        ViewBag.PageSize = pageSize;
        ViewBag.SortByField = sortByField;
        ViewBag.SortAscending = sortAscending;
        ViewBag.SortingEnabled = true;
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
            return PartialView("_Dispensaries", found);
        }

        return View("DispensarySearchResults", found);
    }
```

Placing a breakpoint at the return line I can see that the results are enumerated. There is no DbContext involved or referenced ever in this function. However in the _Dispensaries view I get the error

```
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.ObjectDisposedException: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Source Error: 



Line 38:                <tr class="table-row">
Line 39:                    <td class="item-followers text-center">
Line 40:                        @item.FavoritedBy.Count
Line 41:                    </td>
Line 42:                    <td colspan="1" class="text-center">


 Source File:  d:\Projects\Web\Fhlora\Fhlora\Views\Shared\_Dispensaries.cshtml    Line:  40
```

I have several similar pages that search other entity types and this method works fine for all of them. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? I have tried everything I know.

Comment: And now I just discovered that the error is only happening when I debug locally, it is not happening on the published site.

Answer (score 0):

The object that is stored in the Session is connected to the ObjectContext as you have lazy loading enabled, so that when you run a query against your table, the FavoritedBy reference is populated only when you access it.

Either enable eager loading on the object context or eagerly load the FavoritedBy reference.

You can do that in EF with Include() method in you Dispensary service:

```
var q = Dispensaries.Include(i => FavoritedBy).Sort(..);
```

Comment: `protected override IQueryable<Dispensary> GetFromContext() {
   return DbContext.Dispensaries
    .Include(d => d.Business)
    .Include(d => d.FavoritedBy)
    .Include(d => d.Address)
    .Include(d => d.Ratings.Select(r =>r.Thumbs));
  }`

Comment: As you can see I'm doing this. It works correctly everywhere I use it except here.